# c++: CGAL Periodic 2D regular triangulation: How to implement or alternatives?

Tags: cgal, triangulation

I recently got started with CGAL for implementing some models which required 2D and 3D periodic regular triangulations (weighted Delaunay or power diagram). I have made some progress with the 3D periodic regular triangulations with this [class](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Periodic_3_triangulation_3/classCGAL_1_1Periodic__3__regular__triangulation__3.html).

But I couldn't any similar class from CGAL for the 2D case and since I am new to the CGAL package, I am quite unsure on how to adapt the existing code database to help me with my case. Any help with adapting the code or pointers to the packages which can help me with implementing 2D Periodic regular triangulations will be appreciated!

Comment: Related: https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/pull/4914 (unfinished).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no `Periodic_2_regular_triangulation_2` class, and it is not straightforward to adapt `Periodic_2_triangulation_2` to add weights. It is incidentally being done in https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/pull/4914 because that pull request completely rewrites `Periodic_2_triangulation_2` in a way that will make it easy to add a weighted version, but this is WIP and without any ETA (I am missing time to finish it).

A possible way to go around that limitation would be to add a "fake" third dimension (z = 0) to your 2D data and use a weighted, periodic 3D triangulation?